# Access Database with C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm very new to C#, and I just learn coding as one of my hobbies.

I'm trying to develop a stand-alone Windows application using Visual Studio and an Access database.
I have some difficulties how to access the database.
Project is my table in the Access database and projectname and path are my columns in the project table.

I'm trying to read the folders Name in a certain path and writing the name and path of a folder into my table.

How do I compare and insert only the new folder created?

This is showing an error in my insert syntax!

```
string[] files = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\\SomePath\\Project_1\\Project_1\\Resources");
foreach (string file in files)
{

    string name = new DirectoryInfo(file).Name;
    String Root = Path.GetFullPath(file);
    connection_2.Open();
    OleDbCommand ListWrite = new OleDbCommand();
    ListWrite.Connection = connection_2;
    ListWrite.CommandText= "insert into Project (projectname,path) values ('" + name + "','" +Root+ "') where'"
        + name + "' != projectname  ";
    ListWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection_2.Close();
}
```

Comment: What's the actual resulting query you're trying to execute?  You should really look into using query parameters instead of string concatenation like that.  Currently your code is open to SQL injection, which is not only insecure but is also considerably more error-prone.  Also, normally the comparison in that `WHERE` clause would be the reverse of what you have.  `column != value`, not the other way around.  Also, is it really `!=`?  Or should the operator be `<>`?

Comment: you can read here about sql injection: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/

Comment: Note that you should either escape your backslashes, or use the @ literal, but not both, i.e. `@"C:\SomePath\MyFile"` or `"C:\\SomePath\\MyFile`. Also, `INSERT INTO TABLE() VALUES() WHERE predicate` isn't valid SQL in any RDBMS that I know of.

Comment: Wait, how can an `INSERT` even *have* a `WHERE`?  That doesn't really make sense.  You'd need to either put a unique constraint in the data and handle the error or read the data to see what's there before inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An insert command does not allow a where statement the way you use it.

You will need to query the table for each of the directory names. If the result of the query is not empty, the specific directory name it is already present in the table. Otherwise, you can insert the new name with an insert.

I would suggest to write a new method for that check:

```
public bool DoesFolderAlreadyExistInTable(string folder_name, string path, OleDbConnection connection)
{
    using (var ListWrite = new OleDbCommand("select count(*) as c from Project where name=@name and path=@path", connection)) {
        ListWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", folder_name);
        ListWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", path);
        var result = ListWrite.ExecuteReader();
        return result.Read() && result.GetInt32(0) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well ! it was very hard for me to open a connection to read and open another connection to write in access database

Comment: You do not need separate connections. You can use the same connection for both queries.

Comment: Your Explanation gives me some idea that i can do it !!

Comment: Since I am not a computer programmer  !  Still I am trying to understand your statement . Definitely Now i have a way to search it ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Honestly I dont exactly understand your code but some how i managed to use it and it works now ! I Feel like I have accomplished something now !! Thanks a lot (Y)

Comment: Similarly How do I check if the folder really exist if i have a folder name in my database ! if file doesnt exist in the path ho do i delete it from my data table ? thanks for you Help

Comment: You need to search for all directory entries in you database. You can do that with "select * from Project". You can then iterate over the result of the query and foreach of them you need to check, wether the filename from the table still physically exists on you computer. If not, delete it with another SQL statement "delete from Project where...". You should get more knowledge about SQL. I like this tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Thanks fro sharing the knowledge !! i am learning all the query statements . But ts very hard to implement in c# . Thanks fro your Help

Answer (score 0):

You just need to leave a space after `where`:

```
..where '...
```

However, the best solution for not having such issues as well as SQL injection is to use parameters:

```
ListWrite.CommandText= "insert into Project (projectname,path) values (@name, @path)";
ListWrite.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
ListWrite.Parameters.Add("@path",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Root;
```

Also notice that the `where` clause does not have any sense in an insert statement. You have to handle it from code or putting a unique constraint on the `projectname` column.

Comment: @DownVoter, I would really appreciate on justifying the downvote

Comment: You keep making edits, so I was waiting to see where you ended up. But it isn't a whitespace issue, and your comments about SQL injection are certainly a best practice but don't solve his issue.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller, using the query I wrote without the where clause, I believe solves the issue. In any case I appreciate on letting me know. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

A `WHERE` clause is not valid in an insert statement. I assume what you were attempting to do was prevent duplicate project names. One way you can do this in SQL Server is as shown, I've made the assumption it's valid in Access as well but this isn't always the case.

**SQL**

```
INSERT INTO Project (projectname, path)
SELECT DISTINCT 'yourpath', 'yourroot'
FROM Project
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT projectname FROM Project WHERE projectname = 'yourpath')
```

**C#**

```
ListWrite.CommandText= "insert into Project (projectname,path) select distinct '" + name + "','" + Root + "') from Project where not exists (select projectname from Project where projectname = '" + name + "'";
```

As pointed out by LosWochos and apomene, you should also look into [parameterized SQL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/).